# how to frame web site in android app

Tags: android, web, developer-tools

I would like to build an Android App to frame/view a web site, within the web site is  among already many features that I will later implement into the actual app. What android version should I choose, and how should I put the web site in to android app?

Answer (score 2):

WebView available on Android from very first versions.
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Only thing is that you better to test your App on, at least, two different versions Android - lower than 4.4 and on 4.4(KitKat) or higher. Because sinse that version WebView running by Chrome.